# On a bijection between symmetric subsets of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given a group $G$, we can consider the subset $H$ of $G$ defined by:
$$ H = \{ xyz : x, y, z\in G \textrm{ and } x, y, z \textrm{ are pairwise distinct}\}$$
Let $a\in G$ be arbitrary element. I am interested in understanding the map 
$f_a: H\to H$ defined by
$$
f_a(xyz)=(xa)(ya)(za)
$$
It is not hard to see that image of $f_a$ lies in $H$ (because, for example, if $xa=ya$, then $x=y$), so indeed $f$ is well defined. Also, we can show that $f_a$ is surjective: Given any $xyz\in H$, we have 
$$ f_a(xa^{-1}ya^{-1}za^{-1})=xyz$$
So my question is:

> Is it true that $f_a$ is always a bijection?

Here are some partial results:

a) If $G$ is finite (in which case $H$ is also finite), then $f_a$ is clearly bijection, as every surjection between finite sets is bijection.

b) If $G$ is abelian, then $f_a$ is bijection. This is because $f_a$ can be shown to be injection: If $f_a(xyz)=f_a(x'y'z')$, then $(xa)(ya)(za)=(x'a)(y'a)(z'a)$, and since $G$ is abelian $xyza^{3}=x'y'za^{3}$ which gives $xyz=x'y'z'$, as desired.

So it remains to investigate the case when $G$ is infinite non-abelian group.

By the way, I called $H$ the "symmetric subset" in the title, but feel free to edit it if some other term is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $xyz\mapsto (xa)(ya)(za)$ is not generally well-defined. For example, consider the free group generated by $x$ and $a$: here $xx^{-1}e$ and $x^{-1}xe$ are supposedly sent to different elements.

Comment: Thanks for the explicit example!

Answer (score 2):

This is not well-defined, because the same element $h$ might be written as $xyz$ in many different ways, with different values of $(xa)(ya)(za)$.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! That was tricky, and I am not surprised that I missed it...